# Как перезапустить инициализацию Swiper Slider?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, slider, swiper

На странице, есть Swiper Slider
И после перезагрузки контента с помощью Ajax, слайдер перестает работать. Так как там полностью заменился блок. Как переприсвоить этот блок для слайдера или же перезапустить слайдер вовсе.
Код свайпера не мой, он там очень большой *8600 строчек.
Пробовал просто создать новый слайдер, но там он в модулях и ругаеться на неизвестные функции.
Могу дать ссылку на сам сайт или же прикрепить код. Как лучше?

Comment: что нибудь дайте для уточнения

Comment: КУсочек где вы инициализируете. ajax  сайт и прочее

Comment: @AzizUmarov самим ajax-ом не я занимаюсь, в нем не разбираюсь вообще. И весь сайт тоже в принципе не я делал. [сайт] (http://prime-auto.demiweb.pro/product/kovriki-rezinovye-1-2-3-ryady-6/) мне только нужно перезапустить сам слайдер. Сам файлик скрипта от слайдера в вебпак модулях. пытался делать destroy() для свайпера, не знает ни destroy ни new Swiper(). Сразу прощение, что так мало инфы даю.

Comment: @AzizUmarov если кликнуть по выбору цвета, обновляет картинки в слайдере

Comment: вижу такой код инициализации this.slider = new SLider(`.${classNames.slider.container}`)

Comment: @AzizUmarov Я наверное что то не так делаю. Не работает. Прошу прощения, за тупняк свой

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял "полностью заменился блок" означает, что объекту Swiper был назначен другой элемент в DOM. Возможно Вам поможет метод update():

```
mySwiper.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы исправить эту проблему, вам нужно будет перезапустить Swiper Slider после перезагрузки контента с помощью Ajax. Одним из способов это сделать является переинициализация слайдера, удалив существующую инстанцию Swiper, а затем создав новую.

Вот пример того, как это можно сделать:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {/* настройки слайдера */});

// вызов AJAX запроса

// после успешного запроса переинициализируйте слайдер
mySwiper.update();
```

Этот код пересоздаст экземпляр слайдера с новым контентом. Обратите внимание, что вы можете нужно будет указать настройки слайдера заново, если они были изменены с момента создания слайдера.

Чтобы перезапустить инициализацию Swiper Slider, вам нужно будет сначала удалить текущий экземпляр слайдера, а затем создать новый экземпляр с нужными настройками. Это можно сделать с помощью следующего кода:

```
// сначала удаляем текущий экземпляр слайдера
mySwiper.destroy();

// теперь создаем новый экземпляр слайдера
mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {/* настройки слайдера */});
```

Обратите внимание, что вам нужно будет указать настройки слайдера заново, если они были изменены с момента создания слайдера.